# async-ajax call not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

**Setup:**

I am doing an ajax-jsonp call, which is working fine. The callback function of this changes value of a variable, "myVaraible". Just after the call, there is some if-else logic which works on the value of "myVaraible".

Here is the code:

```
    <script>
        function myfunction() {
            $.ajax({
                url: myURL,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp : "jsonp",
                async: false,
                jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackFn"
            });
        }

        function jsonpCallbackFn(mydata) { 
            alert("inside jsonpCallbackFn");
            if(something) {
                // change value of a variable "myVariable";
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#preview_button").mouseover(function() {
                myfunction();

                alert("after myfunction");
                // do some if-else logic based upon the value of myVariable which is updated by the call to myfunction()
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**The Problem:**

The ajax call remains 'pending', the control moves to the if-else block (effectively executing on the old/stale value of myVariable). And then the ajax call completes. In short, out of the 2 `alert` boxes, `alert("after myfunction");` executes first and then `alert("inside jsonpCallbackFn");`

As you can see, I have already set `async: false,`, but looks like that is not working as expected. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Also, I am not sure if I have explained the entire scenario properly, please let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: RTFM - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation:

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation

So, you'll need to put anything that relies on the results of the request in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no reason you cannot do

```
    function myfunction() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: myURL,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp : "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackFn"
        });
    }
```

and then

```
...
$("#preview_button").mouseover(function() {
    myfunction().done(function(){
        alert("after myfunction");
    });
});
```

jQuery appears to do a bunch of magic behind the scenes to normalize jsonp requests to act somewhat like jquery ajax requests, so I think this is fine.  Let me know otherwise.